# give img title a style for later use in fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, title, fancybox-2

I'm using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and it uses the `title=""` attribute of images to fill the caption of each image. The problem I have is now, that I want to have some words of the caption styled different. The title of each img is created from an array:

```
var img = '<a class="fancybox" title="'+ imgArr[i].forname + ' ' + imgArr[i].surname +'" rel="group1"></a>'
```

and what I try to do is give `imgArr[i].forname` a bolder font so my attempt was:

```
var img = '<a class="fancybox" title="<span style="font-weight: 800;"'+ imgArr[i].forname + '</span> ' + imgArr[i].surname +'" rel="group1"></a>'
```

unfortunenately it does not work. Any clou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would advise you to set the captions inside a (HTML5) `data-*` attribute instead, so when the visitor hovers the link they don't see your `<span>` code.

Second, you have to be very careful with the syntax, mostly when you nest quotes inside other quotes because you could close your declarations earlier than expected; for instance this line of your code:

```
var img = '<a class="fancybox" title="<span style="font-weight: 800;"'+ imgArr[i].forname + '</span> ' + imgArr[i].surname +'" rel="group1"></a>'
```

... the opening double quote of the `style` attribute (`style=""`) in the `<span>` tag is actually closing the `title` attribute of the `<a>` tag, which is also using double quotes, so your code breaks here. Also notice that the `<span>` tag is not properly set, you are doing something like

```
<span style="font-weight: 800;"{forname} {surname}</span>
```

...because you forgot to place `>` just after the `style` attribute.

So try this code :

```
var img = '<a class="fancybox" data-title="<span style=\'font-weight: 800;\'>' + imgArr[i].forname + '</span> ' + imgArr[i].surname + '" rel="group1" href="{target}"></a>'
```

**Notice** how I used and escaped the quotes. Also notice I used the `data-title` attribute instead of `title` (I also set an `href` attribute in case you were missing it ;)

Then, get the `data-title` value inside the `beforeShow` callback in your fancybox custom script like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.title = this.element.data("title");
    } // , // <== comma if other options following
    // your other API options here
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U3HKd/)**

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed and understandable answer. Sorry for the wrong use of the quotes, they are correct in my code, I just typed it by hand in my OP. Anyway this works very good indeed! I just have one question left, does it have any advantage to use `data` attr for this. I'm just asking since the default of fancybox2 seems to be title attr. Thank you!

Comment: The default uses `title` when the caption is just text. For more complex captions (that include html as in your case) I would always recommend `data-*` attributes so you don't see the code on mouse hover